# Get order data with customer details in custom checkout page magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, frontend, knockoutjs

I have create custom checkout Step between shipping and payment step . Now i want to show all the order details and customer fillup details.
Below is the files that i have created for the Custom checkout step

Below is the file (checkout_index_index.xml) i have created for new step in the checkout :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- The new step you add -->
                                        <item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Mycustom_Checkoutnew/js/view/my-step-view</item>
                                            <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                            <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                            <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In the second file (my-step-view.js) there will be js code as follow :

```
define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
], function (ko, Component, _, stepNavigator) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template,
     * <Vendor>_<Module>  - is the name of your module directory.
     */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Mycustom_Checkoutnew/mystep'
        },

        // add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),

        /**
         * @returns {*}
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                // step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'shippingaddress',
                // step alias
                null,
                // step title value
                'Shipping',
                // observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                 * sort order value
                 * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                 * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                 * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                 */
                15
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout steps
         * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
         * for switching to your custom step
         * When the user navigates to the custom step via url anchor or back button we_must show step manually here
         */
        navigate: function () {
            this.isVisible(true);
        },

        /**
         * @returns void
         */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
});
```

Below is the html file (mystep.html) where i want to display all the data of orders and the customer

```
<li id="shippingaddress" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

In the new custom page i want show following things
1)Email 2)Contact 3 )  Address that sellected in previous step
4)Shipping method

If anyone can help me in this then please let me know

In frontend i want show like this please go through the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i guess you are looking following

In your `my-step-view.js` you need to require `'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'` and in function pass like `quote`

```js
let shipping = quote.shippingAddress();
let email = shipping.email || quote.guestEmail;
let method = quote.shippingMethod();
```

**[Update]**

You need to implement related methods in your custom component, with your own logic for example:

```js
    return Component.extend({
        // ...
        getShippingMethodTitle: function () {
            var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod(),
                shippingMethodTitle = '';

            if (!shippingMethod) {
                return '';
            }

            shippingMethodTitle = shippingMethod['carrier_title'];

            if (typeof shippingMethod['method_title'] !== 'undefined') {
                shippingMethodTitle += ' - ' + shippingMethod['method_title'];
            }

            return shippingMethodTitle;
        }
    }
```

and use it in template, for example

```html
<span class="value" data-bind="text: getShippingMethodTitle()"></span>
```

Comment: I need to show that data inside html file. But not getting how to do?

Comment: I've added update and provided an example about possible source and hope this help to understand the general way